# Check if something has children in ROBLOX Lua?

Tags: lua, roblox

I need to check if something has children in ROBLOX Lua. I know of `FindFirstChild(string)` which finds the first child with a name matching `string`, and I have been using that to see if the instance has a certain child in it, but now I want to see if it has ANY at all. I was hoping for something like:

```
if Instance:GetChildren() then
  --Do something
end
```

How do I do something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method will get a table of the Instance's children and check if it is more than 0, meaning it has children.

```
if #Instance:GetChildren() >0 then 
  --It has children!
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the hashtag operator or `table.getn`

```lua
-- Hashtag
if(table.getn(Instance:GetChildren()) > 0) then
    -- ...
end

if(#Instance:GetChildren() > 0) then
    -- ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if Object.GetChildren() then
   --code here
end
```

Comment: For dot notation you have to pass receiver object as the first parameter or use `:` (colon) notation with no arguments. So should be `Instance:GetChildren()`. Also, please add some description to code or link to documentation.

Answer (score 0):

here's one way you could find that out:

```
x = 0

for i, v in pairs(script:GetChildren()) do
    x += 1
end

if x > 0 then
    print("it has children")
end
```

it's not the most efficent but it's pretty simple and works